# OrderBy date format with null values

Tags: c#, linq, date

I have xml of below format

```
<Root>
   <dates>
      <start>20201101</start>
      <end>20201103</end>
   </dates>
   <dates>
      <start>20201101</start>
      <end />
   </dates>
   <dates>
      <start>20201105</start>
      <end>20201108</end>
   </dates>
</Root>
```

I want to order the nodes with two order by conditions. First order by `start` and then `end` using date format. In case `end` node value is empty then i need to keep it at top of the order. So for the above example XML the order will be as below(start date are same for 1st and 2nd , but date is empty for 2nd so it will be considered first)

```
   <dates>
      <start>20201101</start>
      <end />
   </dates>
   <dates>
      <start>20201101</start>
      <end>20201103</end>
   </dates>
   <dates>
      <start>20201105</start>
      <end>20201108</end>
   </dates>
```

```
string xmldoc = "<Root><dates><start>20201101</start><end>20201103</end></dates><dates><start>20201101</start><end></end></dates><dates><start>20201105</start><end>20201108</end></dates></Root>";
            inputDoc.LoadXml(xmldoc);

    XElement e = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(inputDoc));
    var dates = (from res in e.Descendants("dates") select res);
    var newDate = (from ele in dates   
                         orderby DateTime.ParseExact(ele.Element("start").Value, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ascending, DateTime.ParseExact(ele.Element("end").Value, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) descending
                         select ele);
```

With the above code I am not able to handle empty value for `end` date. One option I think is update `end` with DateTime.MaxValue in the initial xml when it is empty then apply order logic. So what is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace empty "end" element with `DateTime.MaxValue` in ordering condition itself:

```
from ele in dates   
    orderby DateTime.ParseExact(ele.Element("start").Value, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ascending,
    String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ele.Element("end").Value) ? DateTime.MaxValue : DateTime.ParseExact(ele.Element("end").Value, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) descending
    select ele;
```